# How to start a new activity after the service ends

Tags: android, service, android-activity, semaphore

So I have two android activities (Activity 1 (**SignUpActivity**), Activity 2(**RegisterActivity**))

The first activity is supposed to start the second one in case of a new user (not the issue)

The trick is that I need to call a certain service first. This service will call a certain server and get some data to provide it for the (RegisterActivity)

So in order to do that there are some possible solutions

1. No need for the service, we can just make the HTTP request from activity 1.
   However I already have a class that extends AsyncTask in SignUpActivity. It has another job (basically signs the user in.
2. I can call the service then call Activity 2 (Which is the trivial solution)
   However the second activity will start before the service ends. That means that it will try to access some data that is still null.

The second solution seems to be easier to implement, however the only way I can think of is using a semaphore lock. Which is something I am not very good at and I am not sure that it is the smartest solution.

I tried to use it but it did not work and I did not feel that this the right way of doing it

What do you think is a smart way to solve that issue?

Comment: How about starting Activity 2 on the service, but after the neccesary data is filled? One line before the service ends?

Comment: +1 @DiegoSuárez. Or may be in a finally block in the onStartCommand of the service

Comment: @Baap James Bond Ka Baap: Not necessarily, if the service contains async work.

Comment: @DiegoSuárez: Use of finally to make sure that the activity2 is started irrespective of response from the server or any other code that may have caused any problem...

Comment: I understand what you say, but how about if the try block (I supose the try block because is necessary for the finnaly) on the onStartCommand contains async calls, and the data is filled on a callback? A common escenary

Answer (score 2, accepted):

- The best option is to create second activity from your first activity when specific task is finished. For this you can create another `AsyncTask` in Activity 1 and start Activity 2 when it is finished (you can have several different-purposes `AsyncTasks` running in paralell)
  **edit**
  to make sure they run in parallel, simply change `yourTask.execute(params)` to 
  `yourTask.executeOnExecutor(AsyncTask.THREAD_POOL_EXECUTOR, params`);` for each task.
- another option is to create Activity 2 from service, when service decides it is needed.

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend using a second AsyncTask since you definitely need to wait for the Service to return before you start the second activity.

Remember that if you execute multiple AsyncTasks concurrently they are executed sequentially by the `AsyncTask` class (which sets up a queue that accepts at most 10 AsyncTasks).

If you really need to run the two tasks in parallel I would suggest implementing a `ThreadPool` and using `Runnable` to pass in the task including launching the second activity.

Here is an example of a [ThreadPool](https://github.com/abid-mujtaba/fetchheaders-android/blob/master/src/com/abid_mujtaba/fetchheaders/misc/ThreadPool.java) from one of my projects. You can pretty much copy it wholesale since it is extremely generic.

An example of the runnable would be:

```
Runnable task = new Runnable() {
    @Override
    public void run() {

       // Call service and wait for it to finish //

       startActivity(new Intent("com.example.project.RegisterActivity);
    }
};

ThreadPool.executeTask(task);    // We use the ThreadPool to run the 'task' Runnable
```

If the code complains about needing to run from the Main Thread you will need to use a `Handler` defined in the First Acitivity to post the `startActivity()` call from within the `Runnable.`